# Repetition character not working for grep in csh when put in double quotes

Tags: scripting, csh

I have posted a question earlier about this but now I understand the problem and thus want to repost. The * character is correctly interpreted in my csh script when not put in double quotes, but when I put it in double quotes, it is not correctly interpreted. Does anyone know how to make csh correctly interpret the * character. Below is my code:

```
#!/bin/csh
#set ans=`grep  -E hello\*i ~/wildcard/helloi.txt`
set ans=`grep  -E "hello\*i" ~/wildcard/helloi.txt`
echo $ans
```

The commented set ans works fine but the uncommented one does not. The input file contains the following :

```
helloiif
helli
helloi
```

All 3 should be printed.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** (with quotations marks, **don't** escape `*`)

```
grep -E "hello*i" ~/wildcard/helloi.txt
```

**Option 2** (without quotation marks, **must** escape `*`)

```
grep -E hello\*i ~/wildcard/helloi.txt
```

Inside double quotes, csh **always** expands things it knows, such as `*`, `$`, etc.